the notification button is not working in a fragment
i'm trying to create a notification button on my project yet it only produces nothing some over code that i have tried made the android app close
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;

Activity activity = getActivity();

public SettingFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);


    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_Notification);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder
            (getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon (R.drawable.baseline_notifications_24)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText ("This is a notification for you");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,mbuilder.build());

}

}
